# The inexplicable approach of an Indian mathematician for Cosecant

Tags: calculus, approximation

I am reading about the old Indian mathematician approximation
$$\csc (z)\simeq \frac{z^4+\pi ^2 z^2+2 \pi ^4}{2 \pi ^4 z-2 \pi ^2 z^3}$$
reminiscent of [Bhaskara's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhaskara_I%27s_sine_approximation_formula).
 I tried to use Taylor series and I got something similar to a Padé approximation
$$\csc (z)\simeq \frac{\frac{11 z^4}{5880}+\frac{3 z^2}{49}+1}{z-\frac{31 z^3}{294}}$$ but the Indian formula is a fairly superior approximation.
How is this possible?

Comment: In which region is it superior?

Comment: the Cuadratic error seem  inferior in z belongs to (-Pi,PI)

Comment: It may have something to do with the fact that we have the correct poles at $0$ and $\pm \pi$ for $$\frac{1 + \frac{1}{2}\bigl(\frac{z}{\pi}\bigr)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\bigl(\frac{z}{\pi}\bigr)^4}{z\bigl(1 - \bigl(\frac{z}{\pi}\bigr)^2\bigr)}\,.$$ Having the poles at different points makes the one with rational coefficients a terrible approximation close to $\pm \pi$.

Comment: Good observation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Indian approximation encodes a large portion of the Weierstrass product for the sine function:
$$ \sin(z) = z\left(1-\frac{z^2}{\pi^2}\right)\prod_{n\geq 2}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right) \tag{1}$$
The problem of approximating $\csc(z)$ boils down to producing approximations for
$$ g(z)=\frac{z}{\sin z}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{\pi^2}\right)=\prod_{n\geq 2}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2 \pi^2}\right)^{-1}\tag{2}$$
which is an even and approximately quadratic function, ranging from $1$ to $2$ on the interval $(0,\pi)$.
Actually
$$ g(z) \approx 1+\left(\zeta(2)-1\right)\left(\frac{z}{\pi}\right)^2+(2-\zeta(2))\left(\frac{z}{\pi}\right)^4\tag{3} $$
leads to an approximation similar to the Indian one
$$ \csc(z)\approx\frac{1+\left(\zeta(2)-1\right)\left(\frac{z}{\pi}\right)^2+(2-\zeta(2))\left(\frac{z}{\pi}\right)^4}{z\left(1-\frac{z^2}{\pi^2}\right)}.\tag{4}$$
and more accurate if $z$ is close to $0$.
$$ \csc(z)\approx\frac{1+\left(\zeta(2)-1\right)\left(\frac{z}{\pi}\right)^2+(\frac{7}{2}-2\zeta(2))\left(\frac{z}{\pi}\right)^4+(\zeta(2)-\frac{3}{2})\left(\frac{z}{\pi}\right)^6}{z\left(1-\frac{z^2}{\pi^2}\right)}\tag{5}$$
is more accurate on the whole interval $(0,\pi)$. *Folklore*: the evaluation of $(5)$ at $z=\frac{\pi}{6}$ leads to
$$ \pi\approx \frac{3}{35}\left(432-\sqrt{156301}\right) $$
with an approximation error of $\approx 3$ parts in one hundred thousands.

Comment: Jack D'Aurizio the above approximation is it not as good as the indian Mathematician

Comment: @Clerk: which one? $(4)$ is better than the Indian approximation only if $z$ is close to zero, $(5)$ is better for any $z\in(0,\pi)$. It comes from interpolating both the values and the values of the derivatives of $g(z)$ at the endpoints of $(0,\pi)$.

Comment: Jack D'Aurizio the above approximation is it not as good as the indian Mathematician the cuadratic error in -Pi ,Pi Indian series is 0.000213614 and your is  0.001622  , I think  the approximation of  g[z] using taylor series is something poor due the poor result.

Comment: @Clerk: how did you compute such error? Since $(5)$ is pointwise better than the Indian approximation (I can add a diagram, if you like) I cannot see how it can have a larger quadratic error.

Comment: even though the formula 5 is the  degree 6 the quadratic mean is  0.157253 in x= -Pi,Pi , I attach an image where you could see visual repressentation of the  the approximations  in the questio you can see.

Comment: @Clerk I think it would make more sense to add your image to your question rather than Jack's answer, or perhaps just share the link in a comment.